# How to detect a disconnection when using Server-sent events on ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, server-sent-events

I have the following SSE handler in ASP.NET

```
Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
while (true)
{
    Response.Write(string.Format("data: {0}\n\n", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
    Response.Flush();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

It runs indefinitely, even after I closed the client application. How to notify the server to stop the handler?

I tried on the client:

```
var source = new EventSource('Handler.aspx');
window.onunload = function() {
     source.close();
}
```

But I didn't succeed.

Comment: If this is just to show a live clock, you may want to look into a JavaScript equivalent that does the same thing.

Comment: @AaronS I'm pretty sure using DateTime.Now is just OPs example.

Comment: @Bala R You're probably right, but doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: You'll need to make your `while` breakable and have the client send a message when it wants the server to break.

Comment: I feel like the best way to do something like this would be a push style request coming from the client, which the server sits on until it's time to respond, responds to, and a new request is immediately opened. Then you never have hanging requests (longer than the timeout, anyway)

Comment: @CrisCarew The whole purpose of using SEE is to avoid pooling.

Comment: @AaronS it's just an example I copied from a SSE tutorial

Comment: @M.Babcock I fear that in a browser crash the client won't be able to send the disconnection message

Comment: @XMLforDummies - In that case I would probably use a timed handshake between the client and server. Every X number of seconds have the javascript send an ajax message to the server and have the server maintain a _kill switch_ of sorts that breaks the loop if it hasn't received a handshake in Y number of seconds.

Comment: @M.Babcock if I have to pool, then there's no point in using SSE.

Comment: @M.Babcock at that point though, it's far more complicated than a simple push system would be, for no real gain since you still have to make requests every x seconds anyway. A good push system would not involve requesting very often, and if your timeout between data is 1000ms, that would be more often than a push system would need to "poll".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `IsClientConnected` property of the `HttpResponse` class to detect client diconnection.

Here is a small example:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
while (true)
{
  Response.Write(string.Format("data: {0}\n\n", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
  Response.Flush();

  if (Response.IsClientConnected == false)
  {
    break;
  }
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

So, using the `IsClientConnected` property you should be able to detect:

1. On the client side closing the source by using `source.close()`.
2. Closing the connection by closing the browser window or navigating to another website.

I've tested my code using ASP.Net 4.0 and Google Chrome.

Comment: this solution only works in the example above because the server is running `Response.Write()` and `Response.Flush()` very often. In my application these commands run only when there's a message to send, which occurs rarely.

Comment: I made a more specific question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771581/how-to-detect-a-disconnection-as-soon-as-it-happens-on-asp-net-without-pooling