# How to detect a disconnection as soon as it happens on ASP.NET without polling?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, server-sent-events

I have a [server-sent events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) handler in ASP.NET

```
Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
while (true)
{
   if(thereIsAMessage)
   {
       Response.Write(message);
       Response.Flush();
       if (Response.IsClientConnected == false)
       {
           break;
       }
   }

   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

The problem is that I can only detect a client disconnection when I send something to the client. And I don't want to poll it, which defeats the whole purpose of using Server-sent events in the first place.

Comment: You can put the isClientConnected() check after the Sleep(...) function. What do you mean with "don't want to pool it"?

Comment: @ZippyV it doesn't matter where `Response.IsClientConnected` is checked. I tried putting it after the Sleep method call to no avail.

Comment: @ZippyV I don't want to pool the client sending empty messages just to check if it is still alive.

Comment: The word you need is *poll*, not *pool*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) - useful for long polling, server notifications won't be difficult to implement. Uses websockets when available. Yours scenario can be implemented very easily using hubs.

Comment: Could not install package 'Microsoft.WebSockets 0.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: are you installing it using Nuget?

Comment: Yes, I am. It is Nuget that gives me that message. I tried changing the Target Framework versions, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in your own code, you can simply modify your example:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
while (Response.IsClientConnected)
{
   if(thereIsAMessage)
   {
       Response.Write(message);
       Response.Flush();
   }

   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

But still, I'm not sure this is optimal implementation using Thread.Sleep approach.